# Unable to display webpart error in sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting this exception while opening the list in browser but no problem in opening in
SharePoint Designer 2010

```
Error while executing web part: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.ParsedCamlQuery.HasMultipleLookupIdInClauses()'.
at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.ApplyOverrideClauses()     
at Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.MetadataNavigation.MetadataNavigationContext.CacheContextFilterOpsAndCaml()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSource.OnSelecting(EventArgs arguments)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments, String aggregateString, Boolean wantReturn, BaseXsltListWebPart webpart, SPListItem& listItem, SPListItemCollection& listItems, String[]& fieldList)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTrasform)
```